# Numerator = Denominator = 0

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

If I have $a=\dfrac{1-1}{1-1}$, is the solution $a=1$, since I can let $b=1-1$, and then I have $a=\dfrac{b}{b}=1$, or is it undefined since I have division by zero (or even else $a=0$ since the numerator is $0$ itself)?

If it makes any difference, I've arrived at this from:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi}\dfrac{1+\cos^3x}{1-\cos^2x}$$

Comment: Have you heard of L'Hopital's rule ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule))?

Comment: @complexist Yes, I have. D'oh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is undefined because you're dividing by $0$.

**Hint:** As for the limit, note that $\forall z\in \mathbb R\left(z^3+1=(z+1)(z^2-z+1)\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of like saying $a=\frac 00 = 1$ because if you let $b=0$, then $a=\frac bb = 1$. However, we know that $\frac 00 $ is undefined.

EDIT: Any number divided by zero is undefined.

Comment: It's more like *asking* if $0/0$ is undefined. Which sounds stupid now I say it, but for some reason seemed different to me then $a/0$ for some $a\ne0$.

Comment: You could reply to any question (for which you know the answer) with "This is kind of like saying [restatement of question]. However, we know that \[answer ]." Great, *you* know that. If *we* knew that, OP wouldn't have asked.

Comment: @OllieFord Sorry, I was under the impression that you knew that $0/0$ was undefined as it is a somewhat well known concept in mathematics. Also, you seemed to know that fact when you wrote "or is it undefined since I have division by zero".

Comment: As per my previous, for some reason I was drawing a distinction between $0/0$ and $a/0, a\ne0$. Couldn't tell you why now.

Comment: Lol okay...sorry for the inconvenience I guess...

Comment: But if you have some limit, like say $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{xa}{xb}$, where $a, b$ are non-zero, maybe functions of $x$, whatever, can you cancel the $x$ from top and bottom, or not? Think that's where my confusion came from.

Comment: If $a, b$ are constant, I suppose you can, since it follows directly from L'Hopital's. But if they're polynomials of $x$?

Comment: @OllieFord Generally, in the case you are doing the limit approach, you are correct. $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac xx = 1$, since $x$ never actually takes on the value of $0$.

Comment: Got it, thanks.